# Find and replace in htaccess files to remove malicious code (but read only SSH access)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssh

Hi I have a bunch of old WordPress installs on some shared hosting.

They have been hacked apparently at root level.  Every (...and there are many) htaccess file has had the same redirect code appended to it. I have now secured them.

I only have read only SSH as its shared hosting.

Anyone got any suggestions on how I could 'find and replace' out the malicious code in the htaccess files without SSH?

Comment: You have some sort of SFTP or something? How did you get your files on your host in the first place?

Comment: @JonLin - Hi I have FTP but the problem is with some of my CMS installs there are hundreds of htaccess files all over the place.

Comment: 1st that's why I would never use shared hosting. Dude get a VPS/cloud at digital ocean for $10/mo lousy dollars. 2nd, since you don't have access, it looks like you will need to download your whole site locally and use something like NotePad++ to find and replace in files. It does it quite well. Or there are other programs that do only that.